# Is it possible to override connection url at client instantiation in Prisma2?

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I am aware that Prisma2 by default wants you to bake the DB connection URL into an environment variable referenced via the Schema. I understand this is needed for CLI operations like migrate to work.

However, at application bootstrap, when the code is running inside a server, I prefer to use something like AWS Secrets Manager for all my application secrets, rather than environment variables.

I am wondering is Prisma 2 provides a way for me to override the connection URL at runtime with something I define at runtime?

I have tried doing this via the `datasources` property of the client options like so:

```
options.datasources.db =
        'postgresql://database_user:thisisasupersecretpassword@hostname:5432/db_name'
```

However it still used what was defined in value that was baked in at client generation time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to override the connection string in the above manner. There is an open issue for that [here](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2609)

Comment: I ended up going with a workaround in that thread, which is to manually kill the environment variable, and then override the connection string in the client options.